# How to add complex inner query to @Query annotaion

Tags: spring-data-jpa

normal sql query which work correctly in db in sql developer passing values for bID and period.

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE abcID IN (SELECT abcID FROM B WHERE bID=1) AND period=3
```

in project at Repository class I passed as this

```
@Query("select a from A where a.abcID IN:(select b.abcId from B where bID=:RevID) and period=:period")
```

error comes as

> Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [select a from A
> where a.abcID IN:(select b.abcId from B where bID=:RevID) and
> period=:period]

I want to know how should I insert above query correctly in `@Query` annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would tell you below points.

1. you can't use select query as `select a from A where a.abcID`. Here **a** is a column so can't define something like `a.abcID`. It need to be `select column from tableA a where a.abcID`
2. Same for query use in `IN` clause. It needs to be like `select b.abcId from tableB b where b.bID=:RevID`
3. What you use as `:RevID, :period` need to be passed as `@Param("RevID"), @Param("period")` to the query method.

This is the query template.

```
@Query("select a.nameOfcolumnYouWantToRetrieve from tableA a where a.someColumn in(select b.someColumn from tableB b where b.columnValueOfTableBYouwantToMatch=:RevID) and a.period=:period")
```

Using this points, try below query.

```
 @Query("select a.id from A a where a.abcID in(select b.abcId from B b where b.bID =:RevID) and a.period=:period")
```

Comment: Now raise ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. why is that?. Thank You Dev

Comment: @LChathurika you should apply the tables that match with your tables. I'll add basic template query. Replace those relevant table names and table properties according to your tables.

Comment: yes. now success. Thank you very much @DevThiman.

Comment: @LChathurika You are welcome. Since this answer fixed your issue, You can upvote the answer also using up^. So it will help for others too. Glad to here it worked.